# Выпадающий список на html

Tags: html, css

Возник вопрос по поводу html.

Я искал в документации и т.д. но почему-то не нашел как вывести определенный элемент из списка в дефолтный.

К примеру. У нас есть список.

```html
<select>
   <option>Выберите оценку</option>
   <option>Зачет</option>
   <option>Не зачет</option>
</select>
```

но первым элементом, после запуска кода будет "выберите оценку". А как сделать так, чтобы был, к примеру, "зачет"? Как установить на него фокус?

Comment: добавь атрибут `selected` в нужный `<option>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плохо искали: http://htmlbook.ru/html/option

Опция - http://htmlbook.ru/html/option/selected

```
<option selected="selected">Зачет</option>
```